# Scala import not found

Tags: scala, import

I'm trying to import a class into the main App object, and I'm getting a "not found" error for the package I am trying to import.

I have a project structure:

```
build.sbt
- src
  - main
    - scala
      SimpleApp.scala
      - somepackage
        SimpleImport.scala
```

SimpleApp.scala:

```
import somepackage.SimpleImport

object SimpleApp extends App {
  val si = SimpleImport()
}
```

SimpleImport.scala

```
package somepackage

class SimpleImport {
  System.out.println("foo")
}
```

When I try to execute the SimpleApp, I get the following error `not found: value SimpleImport`. Whats interesting is that Intellij will tabcomplete the `import somepackage.SimpleImport` but it marks the import as unused, and the instantiation of SimpleImport is marked as `Cannot resolve symbol SimpleImport`.

Whats going wrong here?

Comment: `new SimpleImport()` - The syntax you have would work if you had a **companion object** for your class with an `apply` method.

Comment: That's not the import which is wrong, but the call `SimpleImport()`, corresponding to a `SimpleImport.apply()` function which doesn't exist. If you want to invoke constructor on a plain class, use `new`

Comment: Of course! Thanks! If either of you want to write an answer I'll mark it as correct.